# can someone please explain why a double is called a double in Java?

Tags: java

It honestly seems like one of those things that has a really simple explanation that makes it a thousand times clearer, but I am yet to find such explanation on the internet. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from the answers in the duplicate question: it used to be that `float` was the usual floating-point type and `double` was a double-precision type, which took up twice as much memory and might have been slower on some processors.  This was back in the dark ages when computers had something like 64KB of RAM and we cared about memory usage.  These days there's usually little reason to use a `float`.

Comment: this helped immensely, thank you!